# Connect iPhone to exist MFI device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mfi

Our company develop iOS program, which connect to bluetooth module and get some data. We can't use bluetooth 4.0, because we need to support iPhone 3g/3gs. We need bleutooth device, but won't enroll to MFI program. Do you know exist MFI device, that allow us get data from him wihout enroll to MFI?

Upd. We need detect button push (device have 2 or 3 buttons) and send command for button, device name, and current geolocation (may be geolocation will be get from iPhone). After button push apps send recived data to server.

Comment: You need to specify what kind of data you're trying to get? "some data" could literally be anything.

Comment: Ok, my fail. We need detect button push (device have 2 or 3 buttons) and send command for button, device name, and current geolocation (may be geolocation will be get from iPhone). After button push apps send recived data to server.